# MySQL invisible foreign key table references

Tags: mysql, reference, key

I have an issue on a mysql table. I'm running a loop delete with this:

```
drop procedure if exists del_6m_data;

delimiter $$

create procedure del_data(table_name text, col_name text, del_limit text)

begin
    set @query = concat('delete from ', table_name, ' where ', col_name, ' < date_sub(current_date, INTERVAL 6 MONTH) limit ', del_limit);

    prepare query from @query;
    repeat
        execute query;
    until row_count() = 0 end repeat;

deallocate prepare query;

end $$

delimiter ;
```

The issue is that I have two tables: sourceTable and logTable. Both use InnoDB engine.

sourceTable has info that needs to be worked on for the day. The ID is an auto_increment int.
logTable, just logs what happened using sourceID like interactions, results etc.
There's no reference for sourceID in the logTable DDL or any rule on update or delete.

The problem: Deleting data from sourceTable is randomly setting null the sourceID in logTable.
What could be causing this?
Is there a constraint that's hidden?

I have checked the constraints on information_schema, routines, deletion and update rules. All turned up nothing.

LogTable:

```
CREATE TABLE `LogTable` (
  `id` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `state` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `statedesc` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `scheduledat` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `countbusyretry` int DEFAULT '0',
  `countcongestionretry` int DEFAULT '0',
  `countnoanswerretry` int DEFAULT '0',
  `countglobal` int DEFAULT '0',
  `uniqueid` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `originatecalleridnum` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `originatecalleridname` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `calleridnum` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `calleridname` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `starttime` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `responsetime` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `answertime` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `droptime` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `endtime` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `ringtime` int DEFAULT '0',
  `holdtime` int DEFAULT '0',
  `talktime` int DEFAULT '0',
  `followuptime` int DEFAULT '0',
  `dropreason` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `campaign` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `campaigntype` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `membername` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `reason` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `disposition` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `secondDisposition` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `thirdDisposition` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `dispositionat` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `amd` tinyint(1) DEFAULT '0',
  `fax` tinyint(1) DEFAULT '0',
  `blacklist` tinyint(1) DEFAULT '0',
  `rescheduled` tinyint(1) DEFAULT '0',
  `rescheduledat` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `callback` tinyint(1) DEFAULT '0',
  `callbackuniqueid` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `callbackat` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `deleted` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `deletedat` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `recallme` tinyint(1) DEFAULT '0',
  `agiafterat` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `createdAt` datetime NOT NULL,
  `updatedAt` datetime NOT NULL,
  `UserId` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `QueueId` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `SourceId` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `CampaignId` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `ListId` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `countnosuchnumberretry` int DEFAULT '0',
  `countdropretry` int DEFAULT '0',
  `countabandonedretry` int DEFAULT '0',
  `countmachineretry` int DEFAULT '0',
  `countagentrejectretry` int DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`,`createdAt`),
  KEY `UserId` (`UserId`),
  KEY `QueueId` (`QueueId`),
  KEY `SourceId` (`SourceId`),
  KEY `CampaignId` (`CampaignId`),
  KEY `ListId` (`ListId`),
  KEY `calleridnum` (`calleridnum`),
  KEY `uniqueid` (`uniqueid`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=43886133 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb3
/*!50100 PARTITION BY RANGE (to_days(`createdAt`))
(PARTITION px0Past VALUES LESS THAN (0) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION px202207 VALUES LESS THAN (738733) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION px202309 VALUES LESS THAN (739159) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION px202310 VALUES LESS THAN (739190) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION px202311 VALUES LESS THAN (739220) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION px202312 VALUES LESS THAN (739251) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION px202401 VALUES LESS THAN (739282) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION px202402 VALUES LESS THAN (739311) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION px9Future VALUES LESS THAN MAXVALUE ENGINE = InnoDB) */
```

Comment: `logTable` probably has a foreign key with `ON DELETE SET NULL`

Comment: Please show the output of `SHOW CREATE TABLE logTable;`

Comment: If there's no foreign key constraint in `logTable`, look for a trigger that does this.